# How can I auto capitalize the first word of a sentence using Ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

While typing inside CKEditor/Textbox automatically Every first letter of sentence should be in upper case. 
In multiline text box its working well. But CKeditor its not working.
The code I have tried is below.

```js
var applySentenceCase = function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/.+?[\.\?\!](\s|$)/g, function(letter) {
        return letter.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + letter.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    }); 
}       
var capitalize = function(e) {
    if (this.value.match(/^[a-z]/)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/^./, function(letter) {
            return letter.toUpperCase();
        });
    }
}    
document.getElementById('TextBox1').addEventListener('keyup', capitalize);
document.getElementById('TextBox1').addEventListener('mouseup', capitalize);
document.getElementById('TextBox1').addEventListener('keyup', applySentenceCase);
document.getElementById('TextBox1').addEventListener('mouseup', applySentenceCase);
```

For CKEditor

```
             $(document).ready(function(){
                       var applySentenceCase = function (e) {
                           this.value = this.value.replace(/.+?[\.\?\!](\s|$)/g, function (letter) {
                               return letter.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + letter.substr(1).toLowerCase();
                           });
                       }

             });
             $(document).ready(function () {
                       var capitalize = function (e) {
                           if (this.value.match(/^[a-z]/)) {
                               this.value = this.value.replace(/^./, function (letter) {
                                   return letter.toUpperCase();
                               });
                           }
                       }
             });

                       document.getElementById('CKEditor1').addEventListener('keyup', capitalize);
                       document.getElementById('CKEditor1').addEventListener('mouseup', capitalize);
                       document.getElementById('CKEditor1').addEventListener('keyup', applySentenceCase);
                       document.getElementById('CKEditor1').addEventListener('mouseup', applySentenceCase);

        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please share if anybody knows how it can be worked with CKeditor ?

Comment: using `first-letter` in css is the easiest way.

Comment: @SAM `first-letter` will apply to the first letter of a particular element. Sentences have no concept of separate elements so it won't work. See my comment on Rahul's answer.

Comment: first-letter will capitalize every word first letter. Above code working perfectly for the requirement while typing in textbox. But I want to do in CKEditor. For that we require CKEditor instances. Unfortunately its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with css also

```
p.caps:first-letter{
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z3empmvv/)

Comment: first-letter will capitalize every word first letter. Above code working perfectly the requirement while typing in textbox. But I want to do in CKEditor. For that we require CKEditor instances. Unfortunately its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var str = "hello world";
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});
alert(str);
```